# Profile will not display when called. php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
      <?php
if (!isset($_POST['submitted'])) {//1

// Checs for the ID
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {//2

// MySQL Connect
require_once('mysql_connect.php');

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM websites WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>


// ROW WITH THE ERROR
<?php echo $row['name']; ?></strong><br /><?php echo $row['banner']; ?><? echo $row['description'];?>


 <?php
    } else {
    echo '<font color="red">You have to select a server to view</font>';
    die();
    }
    } else {
    // MySQL Connect
    require_once('mysql_connect.php');

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    // Choose the web for votes
    $query = "SELECT id, votes FROM websites WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $votes = $row['votes'];
    $url = $row['url'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $banner = $row['banner'];

    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
    } // end
    ?>
```

All that is printing is the Name, the rest is not being printed.

I'm just wondering where i'm going wrong?

Its supposed to print the Name, Banner, and description from `$id`.

Comment: You are only selecting the name and id fields in your query.

Comment: can you make this as an answer so i may mark as answered thanks for fast reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify ALL desired fields that you wish to retrieve in your SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, banner, description FROM websites WHERE id = $id";
```

Alternatively, use `SELECT * FROM websites` to retrieve all available rows.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually select `banner` and `description` in your query so they are not available in your resultset.

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, banner, description FROM websites WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: Hm... this answer was submitted way before. Oh well, can't win 'em all I guess. Edit: Oh, I get it now. It was the "comment". It sure took them long enough. But the time difference wasn't much between that and this answer.